# Running ARP Spoof disables internet access on target machine, doesn't intercept traffic as well

Tags: http, man-in-the-middle, wireshark, arp-spoofing

So I'm learning to run MITM attacks on my own WiFi network but I seem to be running into an issue. I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-hack-a-open-wifi/).

The process is simple and I'm running the attack from my Ubuntu laptop. I first enable IP forwarding using `echo > 1 /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_config.` The command runs without an issue. Next up is setting up the ARP Spoof, for which I run these commands in separate terminals.

```
arpspoof -i eno1 -t 192.168.0.101 -r 192.168.0.1
arpspoof -i eno1 -t 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.101
```

`192.168.0.101` is my Windows laptop, in this case, the target.

`192.168.0.1` is my router's default gateway.

The tutorial above says that I have to mention the attacking machine's (Ubuntu laptop's) IP in the -r flag, but that keeps giving me a couldn't arp for spoof host [Ubuntu machine's IP]. I Googled around and found that you have to mention the default gateway (the router's IP) there, so I did and the arpspoof command ran fine.

However, as soon as I run the arpspoof command, the target machine loses internet access and sometimes drops the WiFi connection altogether. Not to mention I am not able to capture any HTTP packets on Wireshark.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

I've tried the solution pointed out [in this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/120333/arp-spoofing-blocks-internet), didn't work for me.

Comment: Just a thought, try setting ``net.ipv4.ip_forward `` to 1 in ``/etc/sysctl.conf`` and reload it using the command ``sysctl -p``.

Comment: No change. I still have the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried it from an Ethernet connection instead of wireless yet?

Comment: @Jeroen My Ubuntu machine is connected via ethernet and the Windows machine is connected via WiFi.